# OracleDataReader fetching multiple results to csv

Tags: c#, oracle, list, csv, datareader

i have following problem:

Im want to use the OracleDataReader to fetch multiple recordsets and write it to a csv file.
My plan was, that i use toe OracleDataReader and write the results into a list (comma separated). After that, i want to write the list into a csv file.

Im searching since 3 days and i didnt find any solution.

```
        OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand(sqlquery2, con);
        OracleDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
        {
            while (reader2.Read())
            {

                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] 
                { 
                    reader2.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                    reader2.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                    reader2.GetValue(2).ToString() 
                });


                listView1.Items.Add(item);
                File.AppendAllText(csvpath, item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```cs
var command = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("Header1,Header2");
while (reader.Read())
{
    builder.AppendLine($"{reader2.GetValue(0)},{reader2.GetValue(1)}");
}
File.WriteAllText(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a header?